# --environment argument given to ember is ignored if export EMBER_ENV is run

Tags: node.js, bash

When I run this in a bash file, the argument `environment` is not received by the ember app:

```
#!/bin/bash

# create nginx.conf
echo "Create nginx.conf from nginx.conf.erb"
export `cat ./.env`
erb ./config/nginx.conf.erb > ./config/nginx.conf

./node_modules/ember-cli/bin/ember serve --environment=acceptance
```

I think it has something to do with the export function. When I put the ember serve command before the export it works.

The `.env` file looks like this

```
EMBER_ENV=development
```

*Running bash 3.2 on Mac OS 10.10 (Yosemite)*

**Edit:** I changed the question because it didn't have all the relevant code

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think it's parsed "the `environment` variable"

Comment: @DaveNewton `--environment` is an option, not a variable.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the tip, it has to do with some other part of the code. So my question is useless ;)

Comment: @chromed Neat, but the pedantry is orthogonal to the OP's verbiage and my parsing of the same. Perhaps your comment would be better addressed to him/her?

Comment: If you want to use the environment `acceptance`, **why** are you using a `.env` file that specifies an environment named `development`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you're giving `ember` two conflicting arguments: You're passing `EMBER_ENV=development` through the environment, and `--environment=acceptance` through the command line. The former tells it to use the environment named `development`, and the latter tells it to use the environment named `acceptance` -- but it can't do both at the same time.

Knowing which of those two conflicting commands `ember` will choose to honor is an item for which you'd need to check its documentation for. Of course, the better thing is just to fix the conflict.

---

I'd suggest doing the following:

```
./node_modules/ember-cli/bin/ember serve "--environment=${EMBER_ENV:-acceptance}"
```

...if you want to honor the `EMBER_ENV` in your file rather than the one on the command line (but fall back to `acceptance` when the file doesn't specify an `EMBER_ENV`). If you use `bash -x`, you'll explicitly see the script passing a `--environment=` appropriate to what's given in the `.env` file.

---

If you always want to use the environment `acceptance`, on the other hand, override or remove the environment after loading it from your file:

```
export `cat ./.env`

# if the file contained `EMBER_ENV`, unset it so our command-line argument is honored
unset EMBER_ENV

./node_modules/ember-cli/bin/ember serve --environment=acceptance
```

---

All that said --

```
export `cat ./.env`
```

is actually a quite buggy way to do things (though it won't break if the only thing you're setting is `EMBER_ENV`, and the only value it has is a single word in all ASCII with no whitespace or special characters). If you trust your `.env` file to be written by a non-malicious user in valid shell syntax, you'd have fewer bugs with:

```
set -a      # automatically export all variables
source .env # run .env as a shell script within the current interpreter
```

If you don't trust your `.env` to be written as a non-malicious script in valid shell syntax, then perhaps something more like:

```
while IFS='=' read -r k v;
  [[ $k ]] || continue               # skip empty lines
  printf -v "$k" %s "$v" || continue # set any variable given as a shell variable
  export "$k"                        # export those variables to the environment
done < .env
```